# removing child component from parent component within map loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child, use-state

In my parent component, I have this code that generates child components based on a usestate hook files:

```
files.map((fl) => <AudioFileListItem key={fl.id} id={fl.id} customer_id={customer_id} name={fl.name} s3_url={fl.s3_url} />)
```

Within that child component, I want to have the ability to delete itself from the files hook of its parent or just delete itself from being rendered.

This is my delete function in the child component:

```
  const handleAudioDelete = (sound_id) => {
    
    var data = {
      "id": sound_id
    };

    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?")) {
      axios.post(`/delete-file`, data).then(function(result) {
        //remove item from react list through hook
        console.log(result.data);
      });;
    }

  }
```

Any idea what I can do?

**Update!**

Added this to parent component and passed it down to child in prop.
It successfully updates the value of files in the parent component but it does not remove the child component from the view. I believe this is because all of the child components are already rendered and the map display is not dynamically showing the values of files.

```
  const handleAudioDelete = (sound_id) => {

var data = {
  "id": sound_id
};

if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?")) {
  var index = files.findIndex(function(o){
    return o.id === sound_id;
  })
  if (index !== -1) files.splice(index, 1);

  setFiles(files);
  console.log(files)
}

  /*
  axios.post(`http://localhost:2000/files/delete-file`, data).then(function(result) {
    //remove item from react list through hook
    console.log(result.data);
  });
  */
```

}

Comment: Does `axios.post(`/delete-file`, data)` return the new data with the one element removed, or is it just a success response from the backend?

Comment: It's asuccess response but I can return the data with the element removed if that makes it easier! @DrewReese

Comment: Well, you can filter locally upon success, or have your API return the "new" data and you can just replace local state. Either will work. The former is less network intensive since you are basically sending a "delta" and the frontend it doing the work, the latter the backend is doing all the work, but the network demand will be more.

Comment: Can you share a more complete code example of the state being updated and how it's passed around to be rendered, and where/how it's rendered?

Comment: @DrewReese full code pasted!

Comment: In the parent, `files.splice(index, 1);` does an [in-place](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) mutation. You are mutating the `files` state array and then saving it back into state. You should return a new array reference, i.e. the `filter` function. Alternatively you can shallow copy the array first, something like `const newFiles = files.slice().splice(index, 1);` and then `setFiles(newFiles);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `files` is state, use the element `id` to filter the state, return all file elements with non-matching `id` property.

```
const handleAudioDelete = (id) => {
  const data = {
    id
  };

  if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?")) {
    axios.post(`/delete-file`, data)
      .then(function(result) {
        setFiles(files => files.filter(fl => fl.id !== id));
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: It says that setFiles is not defined. Anyway I can import it to the child component?

Comment: @Juliette Ah, this is/was assuming that `handleAudioDelete` lived in the same parent component with the `files` state, and `handleAudioDelete` is passed as a prop to wherever a remove button is rendered. If you could update your question to include a more comprehensive parent-child code example I can update to a more accurate answer.

Comment: Actually I can just move it to the parent state that works too thanks !

Comment: @Juliette And yeah, if you wanted to you could pass the `setFiles` state updater function to a child component.

Comment: I will most definitely upvote and give you the answer credits. I had an issue that came up when I modified the parent component. I updated my question above to reflect that.